# PHPUnit assertDatabaseHas with Laravel and Inertia

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, inertiajs

I have a Laravel 8 setup that utilises Intertia.js. I'm trying to test my post routes to store new resources and want to assert that the database has the new record stored, using the `assertDatabaseHas()` method.

**Controller.php**

```
public function store(SlotCreate $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        $slot = CreateSlot::dispatchNow($request);

        return redirect()->back()->with([
            'message' => 'Slot Created Successfully.',
            'slot' => new SlotResource($slot)
        ]);
    }
```

**CreateSlotTest.php**

```
public function testCreateSlot()
    {
        $response = $this->actingAs($this->teamAdminOne)->post('/slots', [
            'start_time' => '09:00',
            'end_time' => '10:00',
            'max_bookings' => 3
        ]);

        $response->assertStatus(302);

        $this->assertDatabaseHas('slots', [
            'id' => ???
            'team_id' => $this->teamAdminOne->currentTeam(),
            'start_time' => '09:00',
            'end_time' => '10:00',
            'max_bookings' => 3
        ]);
    }
```

When I debug the session I can see the slot that I added to the `with()` method but I can't figure out how to access it.

I'd like to know if I'm returning the slot correctly in the controller and if yes, how do I access the response to assert if the database has this record?

Comment: You can access the variable inside the session simply by: `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::get('slot')`

Comment: @TohidDadashnezhad Perfect. You can add as answer and I'll accept. Out of interest, is this the correct way to return data from the controller in Inertia?

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help you. To be honest, I've never experienced Inertia, personally, I always prefer to separate the backend and frontend code and make an individual project for each one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually when you call `redirect()->with()`, it adds the variables into the session by calling the `session()->flush()` method. So in this case you can retrieve the variables via `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session` facade.

```
$slot = Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::get('slot')
```